# How to get colourful integrated terminal ("cmd") in VS Code

Tags: cmd, terminal, visual-studio-code

Recently after **updating** my **VS Code** I saw the following image in the `Release Notes` (in the *Split terminal feature* section)

[image: Nice colorful terminal]

I can't figure out a way to add such *Syntax Highlighting* in my terminal. Obviously, this is *bash* in the integrated terminal. Well, I'm using *Command prompt* and I don't seem to find any satisfying answer for getting colored text on my terminal (that does not mean just foreground or background color). Mine looks like...

[image: My dull terminal]

Is there a way to fill this dull terminal with interesting text colors.

Comment: Normally `cmd` isn't colored - but see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/11/introducing-the-windows-console-colortool/) for example.

Comment: it would be great to have project-level syntax colorizer for terminal implemented as .dll built by flex/bison/g++ compiler in project/.vscode

Answer (score 0):

The upper one is the output of something called "node"
the second one is your terminal

so the first one is an outputstream of e.g. an program which formats stuff a bit else, also is output of an program in a terminal displayed differently than just the shell

and now to your question, the shell inside vscode has the same theme like your standard shell

so windows -> cmd, ubuntu bash, ...

Comment: Colored texts work for 'bash' also, not only 'node'. Check out the following link... [VS Code Split Terminal Feature GIF](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_21/terminal-split.gif)

Comment: but isn't the color theme configured somewhere os-specific? and vscode is just grabbing it from there..?